# Unable to load the data product of Open Data Cube dataset image

Tags: jupyter-notebook, open-data-cube

I'm trying to load data product of the indexed Open Data Cube dataset image through the Jupyter Notebook. In this I'm using Resourcesat-2 AWiFS Data. The method used is shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datacube
dc = datacube.Datacube(app = 'my_app', config='C:/Users/Dell/datacube.conf')
list_of_products = dc.list_products() 
list_of_products
```

After this it showed the list of product but when I tried to load the Data product using following method:

```
ds_2019 = dc.load(product = 'AWiFS_21May19',
      longitude = (77.0, 78.0), 
      latitude = (27.0, 28.0), 
      output_crs = 'EPSG:4326', 
      resolution = (-0.00045, 0.00045)) 

print(ds_2019)
```

It showed the following output:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
    *empty*
```

Can anyone please tell what's wrong here and how to load a particular data product in the notebook?

I am doing a local installation of Open Data Cube and indexed some datasets with PostgreSQL on a Windows 8.1 system.

Comment: Hello @Chhavi, did you checked if you receive an empty return using any other data? https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/api/generate/datacube.Datacube.load.html

Comment: @YogeshChavan Yes, I was able to load the data product of LISS3 but in case of AWiFS I have received empty return.

Answer (score 2):

Usually if you get an empty return, there is no data over your area of interest.

Try loading a dataset searching by extents, like this:

```py
datasets = dc.find_datasets(product='AWiFS_21May19', limit=1)

data = dc.load(datasets=datasets, output_crs='EPSG:4326', resolution=(-0.00045, 0.00045))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked